# return more than one variable from matlab to python, using python-matlab-bridge

Tags: python, matlab

It is easy to return one variable from Matlab using

```
res = mlab.run_func('path/to/jk.m', {'arg1': 3, 'arg2': 5})
```

How can I return more than one variable from Matlab. For example, my .m function is as below

```
function [lol, sos] = jk(args)
    arg1 = args.arg1;
    arg2 = args.arg2;
    lol = arg1 + arg2;
   sos = arg1 * arg2;
end
```

Comment: maybe your matlab function returns one struct with 2 fields as result?

Comment: With python-matlab-bridge you are refering to the Matlab Engine for Python (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html) or to some 3rd party library?

Comment: I am refering to this one: https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge